# Simple.OData.Client fails with Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, odata, simple.odata

The following little piece of code works great in a console application, but in a Silverlight 5 application (where I need it!) it fails by throwing a *NotSupportedException*:

```
    var client = new ODataClient("http://MYSERVER:9000/OData_v4/ProductionDb/");

    try
    {
        //This statement throws in Silverlight 5 but not in a .NET 4.5 Console application!!??
        var Meter = await client
            .For("MyEntityName")
            .Top(1)
            .FindEntryAsync();

        foreach (var entry in Meter)
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value));
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format( "Exception {0}: {1} ", ex.GetType().ToString(), ex.Message ));
    }
```

Why doesn't it work in Silverlight? According to the documentation it should work with Silverlight right out of the box....?

I used NuGet to install *Simple.OData.Client* vers. 4.13.0 (=latest stable) into my Visual Studio 2015 Silverlight project.

Comment: Can you paste the exception message ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot: The exception has a blank message, but it also has an inner exception (also a NotSupportedException) that shows the message: "Specified method is not supported".

Comment: I can try to debug this problem but do you have a stack trace for the error? It can ring a bell.

Comment: See separate answer at bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to your MainPage constructor, right after InitializeComponent():

```
HttpWebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
HttpWebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

This should fix the problem (at least if I was able to run your code with these changes). Quite frustrating but has nothing to do with OData library. You can read more about the issue here: https://mattduffield.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/silverlight-specified-method-is-not-supported-on-this-request/

Comment: Hi Vagif. Fantastic - I would never have figured that out myself! However, I still have to try out your solution, but in any case thank you very much for your efforts. I will come back and mark this answer as working as soon as I have tried it out.

Comment: Of course you should try it. Never believe strangers 

Comment: Hi Vagif. It worked - but now I get a SecurityException instead. I googled it at found out that I need to enable an access policy (cross-domain access) on the server side by placing an access policy xml file on the web server. However, my service is self-hosted. How can I add the required access policy programmatically?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea, haven't had such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var Meter = await client
            .For<MyEntityName>()
            .Top(1)
            .FindEntryAsync();
```

Found [here](http://www.odata.org/blog/advanced-odata-tutorial-with-simple-odata-client/)

Comment: It makes no difference - still the exact same exception.

Comment: Can you try again with `.For<MyEntityName>()` instead of `.For<MyEntityName>`

Comment: That's exactly what I did (I get a syntax error if I leave out the paranthesis)

Comment: You should be able to recreate the problem by simply creating a new, blank Silverlight application and adding my code to the MainPage.xaml.cs (override the OnMouseLeftButtonDown method  for example).